# LWC datatable multiple row actions open at same time

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

[image: Only one action dropdown should be open at a time]

Experiencing this issue above. The error is when I click on many row actions it won't close the previous one and then you will have many open. I'm trying to find a solution to close all and open the most recent clicked. Thanks

It is a lightning web component.

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-p-horizontal_small">
    <div class="slds-col">
        <template if:true={loaded}>
            <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={lineItems}
                    columns={columns}
                    onrowselection={handleRowSelection}
                    onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                    sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                    sorted-by={sortedBy}
                    onsort={handleColumnSort}
                    selected-rows={selectedRowsIds}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </template>

        <template if:false={loaded}>
            <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading"></lightning-spinner>
        </template>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
handleRowAction(event) {
    try {
        if (event.detail.action.name === 'edit') {
            const editRowEvent = new CustomEvent('rowedit', {
                detail: { row: Object.assign(event.detail.row) }
            })
            this.dispatchEvent(editRowEvent);
        } else if (event.detail.action.name === 'delete') {
            const deleteRowEvent = new CustomEvent('rowdelete', {
                detail: { row: Object.assign(event.detail.row) }
            })
            this.dispatchEvent(deleteRowEvent);
        }
    } catch (exception) {
        processScriptThrownException(this, exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: @S, Bailey  have you try testing it in multiple browsers?

Comment: @AmerBearat I just tried in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Edge. All show the same problem.